# Inequality $\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{N}}{16}\right\rfloor \geq \frac{\sqrt{N}}{c}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $N$ be a natural number. Is it possible to show that $\left\lfloor \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{16}\right\rfloor \geq  \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{c}$ for some constant $c$ and inequality holds for all natural $N\geq 1$?

Comment: Such a $c$ must satisfy the equation for $N=1$, yielding $0 \geq \frac 1c$, so $c$ is negative, and conversely if $c < 0$ then of course the above holds.

Comment: For $N<256$, the left-hand-side equals $0$. You're not going to get inequality in such cases if $c$ is a positive constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true for any negative value of $c$.

However it cannot be true for any positive value of $c$, because for $N=1$, you have $\left\lfloor \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{16}\right\rfloor = 0 < \frac{\sqrt N}{c}$

---

If you only want the inequality to hold for large enough values of $N$, then any value $c>16$ will do the trick eventually, since, if $N$ is large, so is $$\frac{\sqrt{N}}{16} - \frac{\sqrt N}c = \frac{\sqrt{N}(c-16)}{16c},$$ meaning that $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{16} - \frac{\sqrt N}c$ will eventually be bigger than $1$.

Comment: However, I am working through one paper and one of it lemma uses the fact that $\lfloor \sqrt{N}/ \pi\rfloor>\sqrt{N}/4$ for $N>0$

Comment: @RFZ The paper is probably only interested in large values of $N$. I mean, it doesn't make what they wrote *correct*, but it's more on the *sloppy*, rather than *outright false*, side of "incorrect".

Comment: Thanks for answer! Maybe you are right. I need to pay attention